# Php multiupload mysql save to a single id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. The problem is For e.g, I complete the form once, but upload three images. Now what happens is, the data that I completed the form with is created three times in the DB, each one with it's own ID to account for the three uploaded images. I want to collect all images one id at PHPMYADMİN. Thank you for help.

MY PHP CODE:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $file_id = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_name = $key.$rd.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
         $nid=74;
        if($file_size > 9999097152){
            $error .='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/$file_name");
        $name_array=mysql_real_escape_string($file_name);
        $value_insert[] = "('" . $name_array . "')";
         $values_insert = implode(',', $value_insert);

        $desired_dir="uploadfiles". $file_name;
        $query="INSERT into files(`id`,`file_id`,`filename`,`type`,`size`) VALUES('74','$file_id','$file_name','$file_type','$file_size'); ";





        if(empty($error) == true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir) == false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){

                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }

            mysql_query($query);    

        }
        else
        {
                print_r($error);

        }
    }
    if(empty($error))
    {
    echo " <div class='alert alert-success'>Your Files are Uploded Successfully . <a href='viewphotos.php'>View Photos</a> |<a href='addevent.php'> Add new Photos</a></div>";

    }
}
```

The id 74 is a example, There is in database; just like `$_SESSION["id"]`